# C++ Refactoring, Extension Methods typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, legacy

I have a legacy c++ application and refactoring it step by step.
I came across lots of typedef as below

```
typedef std::vector<class OrganisationData *> VECTP_ORDATA;
VECTP_ORDATA g_OrganisationData;
```

There are lots of free functions using on g_OrganisationData currently. What I feel is, previous developers should have made a class and made it more object based instead of free function spreaded everywhere.Currently I am in a process of grouping relevent functions together and make it as a static class around  `g_OrganisationData` and call static functions whereever necessary.

Another option is grouping the function together under a single header file and use it. Is there any other best alternatives? Due to the nature of the code, I can't make changes step by step only.

Comment: Your `typedef` makes `VECTP_ORDATA` an alias for `std::vector<class OrganisationData *>` (a vector of pointers to `class OrganisationData `). `VECTP_ORDATA g_OrganisationData;` creates one such vector. There may be a very valid reason for the vector of pointers depending on where the classes are instantiated.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica yes, but the functions which uses g_OrganisationData is spreaded everywhere instead of being cohesive. That's my worry

Comment: Since it is a *vector of pointers* -- it could be picking up new pointers all over the code. (understand I'm guessing at what the code "could" be doing). It wouldn't be uncommon.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, nope, it initialised once then not picking up new pointers all over the code. I agree with your "could be", it's hard to give 100% correct answer without knowing entire scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion will be to put related functions in appropriately named `namespace`s instead of making them `static` member functions  of a `class`.

Examples:

```
namespace RenderAPI
{
   // Put all rendering related functions here
}

namespace PersistenceAPI
{
   // Put all read from disk and write to disk functions here.
}

namespace MySuperCoolBusinessLogicAPI
{
   // Put all the functions dealing with your super cool business logic here.
}
```